# How to convert this pandas dataframe from a tall to a wide representation, dropping a column

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, reshape

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Variable':    {0: 'Abs', 1: 'rho0', 2: 'cp', 3: 'K0'},
                   'Value':       {0: 0.585, 1: 8220.000, 2: 435.000, 3: 11.400},
                   'Description': {0: 'foo', 1: 'foo', 2: 'foo', 3: 'foo'}})
```

I would like to reshape it like this:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Abs':  {0: 0.585},
                    'rho0': {0: 8220.000},
                    'cp':   {0: 435.000},
                    'K0':   {0: 11.400}})
```

How can I do it?

```
df3 = df.pivot_table(columns='Variable', values='Value')
print(df3)
Variable    Abs    K0     cp    rho0
Value     0.585  11.4  435.0  8220.0
```

gets very close to what I was looking for, but I'd rather do without the first column `Variable`, if at all possible.

Comment: Wow, thank you for the way you formatted your dataframes. makes it so much easier to debug!

Comment: do you expect to have more than 1 entry (i.e., 2 instances of `Abs` in the dataframe)? `pivot_table` will aggregate all entries using their mean.

Comment: @DavidKaftan thank you! It's the standard format used in [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html). I try to use it whenever it's possible, to make life easier to people here 

Comment: @DavidKaftan you're right. In this particular case I'm not expecting to have 2 instances of `Abs` or any other variable in the dataframe, since these are material properties and it would make no sense to have two different values of, say, heat capacity, for the same material. But an alternative solution could be useful for other people who google my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try renaming the axis()

```
df3 = df.pivot_table(values='Value', columns='Variable').rename_axis(None, axis=1)
```

additionally if you want to reset the index

```
df3 = df.pivot_table( columns='Variable').rename_axis(None, axis=1).reset_index().drop('index',axis=1)
df3.to_dict()
# Output 
           {'Abs': {0: 0.585}, 
           'K0': {0: 11.4}, 
           'cp': {0: 435.0}, 
           'rho0': {0: 8220.0}}
```

Comment: the result is not exactly what I requested. Please add the outputs of your command to your question, it's easier for you to format it nicely that it is for me in a comment.